# Super Meat Boy no-death achievements

Tags: achievements, super-meat-boy

I have Super Meat Boy for Steam and there are the no-death achievements, like Wood Boy, that expect you to complete a world without dying.

What exactly do I have to do to get one of these achievements? Do I have to run through all levels in a world in order, possibly including level -1 and the Boss? Or can I do the levels out of order assuming I don't die on any attempts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here a video guide on game trailers.

http://www.gametrailers.com/user-movie/super-meat-boy-wood-boy-achievement/352916

You have to complete 20 levels in a chapter without dying. You can complete the levels in any order as well.

Comment: Also, I believe that the achievements are not earn-able with Steve (aka Mr. Minecraft) as he sort of trivializes the whole thing.

Comment: I would *love* if this achievement required only 20 levels without dying and couldn't care less about consecutivity.

Comment: Do you have to complete these levels consecutively? Or does the achievement unlock after each level has been passed with no deaths?

Comment: @Crag -- sounds like a perfect topic for a new, separate question!

Comment: @Crag -- I just earned Woodboy; unfortunately, it does like the levels have to be beaten consecutively. Even if you complete a level without dying, you can't earn the achievement until you complete 20 levels in a row without dying.

Comment: I can also confirm that the levels do not need to be completed in order, but simply completed. I got Woodboy after level 1-18 (I started on 1-19)

Answer (score 3):

To get the no-death achievement of a chapter, **you have to complete the 20 main levels without dying**. There are separate achievements for light world and dark world.

- you can freely switch between characters, but Steve and Meat Ninja don't count for these achievements,
- you can do the levels in any order,
- you can switch between levels as long as you don't die (**so you can quit a level just before dying**).

You can take some decisions to make the achievement easier:

- go from the hardest level to the easiest level,
- choose the best character for each level.

It's better to unlock all characters before trying to do the no-death achievements.

You can now find a lot of guides in dedicated websites or in the [game's steam page](http://steamcommunity.com/app/40800/guides/#scrollTop=0).